# Can't change the boot order in BIOS

Tags: boot, bios, uefi, bootloader, thinkpad

I recently bought a Thinkpad X230. I want to install a Linux distro on it, but I've been unable to change the boot order in the BIOS to boot from USB. I can access the BIOS, but I can't edit the order in the Boot section, and can't even hover the selection above the options for booting.

'One-time' boot order with F12 also doesn't work, since the USB is one of the 'Locked options' which aren't even in the boot order (and I can't change that).

Have any of you dealt with this issue before? I haven't found any solutions online, please help. Here is the system information from Windows 10:

[image]

Comment: Have you consulted the X230's manual or Lenovo's support site?

Comment: I believe Lenovo has an option to lock the boot order in the UEFI/BIOS. Have you checked whether that's enabled on your PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This laptop had a locked BIOS. The seller provided me with the BIOS password upon request, and I managed to unlock the BIOS. After that, I could change the boot order with no issues. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a refurbed T430 I purchased a while ago, for me the issue was the "Boot Order Lock" option under the Startup tab in the BIOS had been enabled by the previous owner.